# Binding Raw JSON With The Fields Of Different Classes

Tags: json, gson

I am getting following JSON string through http webservice:

***Raw JSON String:***

```
[
 {
   field1OfClass1:"someValue",
   field2OfClass1:"someValue",
   field1OfClass2:"someValue",
   field2OfClass3:"someValue"
 } 
]
```

***Classes:***

```
class Class1
{
    String field1;
    String field2;
}

class Class2
{
    String field1;
}

class Class3
{
    String field2;
}
```

In GSON is there any way to parse above said JSON string with the fields of depicted classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As best I know, there is no built-in feature of Gson to automagically map the example JSON structure to the example Java data structure in the original question.  Custom deserialization processing is necessary.